# Json Rest Service in Message Broker

Tags: json, rest, esb

I have a requirement to build a Json Rest Service in Websphere Message Broker(ESB) for the below use cases.
So ESB (WMB) needs to create Rest based service integration to the below rest service to the mobile Apps and internally ESB will interact the back end Service.

So my question is How many end point URL the ESB needs to expose to the customer (Mobile App), Is that 4 Endpoint URI as each Use case? Or 1 endpoint URL with multiple http methods?

Example in SOAP based Webservice, We have one service contract with multiple operation, Where Consumer system will have one end point URL with multiple operation,  like wise, Do we have same approach with one endpoint URL with multiple methods?

How many Endpoint interface that  ESB needs to expose to consumer? IS that one or four?

### Use Cases:

1. Fetch the list of items
2. Fetch the particular ItemDetails
3. Update /edit the item details
4. Store the video files related to the items into Database.

It would be grate and appreciated your quick answer.,

Thanks,
KK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to read about REST first as it's quite different from SOAP. For this, you would probably need two URLs:

### Fetch the list of items:

```
GET /items
```

### Fetch the particular ItemDetails:

eg. to fetch item with ID 123:

```
GET /items/123
```

### Update /edit the item details:

```
PUT /items/123
```

eg. with data `{title:"Hello"}`

### Store the video files related to the items into Database:

This is more complicated because you will be dealing with two resources - the video file and the "item" (which presumably contains more info, such as title, description, etc. about the video). You could do that with two API calls:

```
POST /videos
```

The POST data will be the video file. Then this call could, for example, return the video file ID (eg. it would return `{id:3}`). You would then update the item with this new information:

```
PUT /items/123
```

Data: `{video_id=3}`

Comment: Thanks and appreciate your quick response.  lau.

Comment: It's certainly very useful. Thanks.

Comment: In Websphere Message Broker, If we want expose RESTful service to the Rest client, with different url: like ,

Comment: In Websphere Message Broker to expose RESTful service with following http URL with POST method to hide the data from sending through URL. So can you suggest implementation in  MB, Is that one HTTPInput Node with wilecard (*)./ProductService/*' to receive all the http request in one interface in WMB and internally call different sub flow to handle http request separately? And consider them is one service and have multiple endpoint URL? So could you please suggest the right approach http://<hostname:port>/productService/getItems,/productService/getAddress, /productService/getCustomerHistory,

Comment: @Karuna, if you have additional problems, please post a new question so that everybody can contribute (you'll probably get more answers this way). Also comments aren't very convenient to discuss problems in details.